# Error in Xcode 8.3 - "object has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent"

Tags: swift, xcode, exception, binding

I'm suffering from an issue which appears with Xcode 8.3 (sample works fine in version 8.2.1)

I created a NSTextField and connect the value binding to ViewController self.myDict.String
The button calls "change"

When I start the app the string "Initial String" is displayed in the Textfield.
When I click on the button I get an exception

> Cannot update for observer  for
>   the key path "myDict.String" from , most likely because the value for the key "myDict"
>   has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check
>   the KVO-compliance of the exceptiontest.ViewController class.

The issue first appeared in the latest Xcode 8.3 and works fine on older versions.
Could this be a bug or do I have some kind of design error?

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    dynamic var myDict = ["String":"Initial String"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func change(_ sender: Any) {
        self.willChangeValue(forKey: "myDict")
        myDict["String"] = "New String"
        self.didChangeValue(forKey: "myDict")
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem, also with a `dynamic` Swift dictionary ... Also only on Xcode 8.3

Comment: Same here. Just started seeing this problem with Xcode 8.3. I'm wondering if it is a bug in Swift 3.1 or an intentional change.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple. Will update with any response.

Comment: Also submitted a bug report, and created a related openradar: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5533996725305344

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 8.3.1. I haven't gotten any response on the bug submission yet.

Comment: The issue still exists in Xcode 8.3.2 - I've also filed a bug at Apple and got the "duplicate" response. So at least it seems that someone has a look onto this

Comment: Also got the "duplicate" response on my bug report... I also hope that it means they are looking into it !

Comment: Just some additional information - this problem only appears to apply to dictionaries. Strongly typed objects with declared dynamic properties seem to work fine. I have updated my bug report to include this.

Comment: Specifically, it only appears to apply to Swift-native dictionaries. `NSDictionary` seems to work fine as well.

Comment: Yes indeed, using `NSMutableDictionary` as workaround worked for me. But the performances are not the same and I would prefer to use the new Swift dictionary.

Comment: It's quite disappointing that this issue wasn't fixed for 2 months now (and 3 new releases since then)

Comment: This still appears to be broken in Swift 3.2 and 4.0 (Xcode 9).

Comment: Yup. I gave up hope and coded a workaround. Very disappointing especially because there's still an open bug report at apple